# R: How to create formula object in order to allow proper text representation?

Tags: regex, r, formula, gsub

I am creating a fairly long formula and when I try to get the formula elements back I find that random "\n" elements have been inserted. 
The regex tools work ok on a plain string, I guess I am doing something wrong in creating the formula in the first place. How can I create the formula object properly? If the formula representation cannot be changed that would help me already because then I can stop trying and look elsewhere.

This is a sample formula:

```
myBigFormulaA <- as.formula(paste("Y ~ ",paste(seq(0,200,1),collapse="+")))
```

I have tried to Reduce/deparse:

```
Reduce(paste, deparse(myBigFormulaA))
```

Which outlines that some spaces have been inserted:

```
    [1] "Y ~ 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 +      14 + 15 + 16 + 17 +
 18 + 19 + 20 + 21 + 22 + 23 + 24 + 25 +      26 + 27 + 28 + 29 + 30 + 31 + 32 + 33 + 34 + 35 + 
36 + 37 +      38 + 39 + 40 + 41 + 42 + 43 + 44 + 45 + 46 + 47 + 48 + 49 +      50 + 51 + 52 + 53
 + 54 + 55 + 56 + 57 + 58 + 59 + 60 + 61 +      62 + 63 + 64 + 65 + 66 + 67 + 68 + 69 + 70 + 71 + 
72 + 73 +      74 + 75 + 76 + 77 + 78 + 79 + 80 + 81 + 82 + 83 + 84 + 85 +      86 + 87 + 88 + 89
 + 90 + 91 + 92 + 93 + 94 + 95 + 96 + 97 +      98 + 99 + 100"
```

I have also tried regexp:

```
gsub(" ", "", as.character(myBigFormulaA)[3])
```

Which clearly shows that "\n" are inserted:

```
"0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+
35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45+46+47+48+49+50+51+52+53+54+55+56+57+58+59+60+61+62+63+64+65+66+
67+68+69+70+71+72+73+74+75+76+77+78+79+80+81+82+83+84+85+86+87+88+89+90+91+92+93+94+95+96+97+98+
99+100+101+\n102+103+104+105+106+107+108+109+110+111+112+113+114+115+116+117+118+119+120+121+122+
123+124+125+126+127+128+129+130+131+132+133+134+135+136+137+138+139+140+141+142+143+144+145+146+
147+148+149+150+151+152+153+154+155+156+157+158+159+160+161+162+163+164+165+166+167+168+169+170+
171+172+173+174+175+176+177+178+179+180+181+182+183+184+\n185+186+187+188+189+190+191+192+193+
194+195+196+197+198+199+200"
```

Any pointers how to handle this behaviour are most welcome.

Comment: use `\s` instead of empty space . Because `\s` would match `\n` characters also. `gsub("\\s", "", as.character(myBigFormulaA)[3], perl=TRUE)`

Comment: you can *almost* do this by increasing the `width.cutoff` argument of `deparse`, but there is an upper limit of 500, which doesn't quite work for your example (sigh -- I don't know why this hardcoded limit can't be increased to something larger, e.g. 2000 ...)

Comment: Ah, well matching on `\s` does the trick. Unfortunately the issue is within some package I am using. Guess I will have to learn to to fix packages now :) Thanks for the pointer!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used

```
safeDeparse <- function(x,collapse=" ") {
    paste(deparse(x),collapse=collapse)
}
```

for this task. You can *almost* do this by increasing the `width.cutoff` argument of `deparse`, but there is an upper limit of 500, which doesn't quite work for your example (sigh -- I don't know why this hardcoded limit can't be increased to something larger, e.g. 2000 ...)

Comment: My primary concern is not the parsing, but how to make the formula object behave properly. I have limited control regarding the function that is misbehaving. I was thinking to fake the formula object and see how far I'd get, e.g., `funk <- c("","",""); funk[2] <- "Y"; funk[3] <- "~"; funk[3] <- myBigFormulaA` Is this even a good idea?

Comment: Accepting this since is closest to the solution this is likely to get.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to do, i.e. in what way the formula object is not "behaving properly" (you might want to have a look at `?reformulate` ...). If you added more context to your question I could try again ...